# How To use a date calendar in textbox

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I have a fairly simple question that I have not been able to figure out, even while searching through here.

I have the following text-box named LockedOutDate:
[image]

The goal is for this textbox to use a date calander where the user is able to select the date rather than manually enter it in like I was doing before. How would I do this?

Here is my current code:

**XAML:**

```
<TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,9,5,8" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Text="Locked Out Date:"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtDate" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding LockedOutDate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
```

**View-Model:**

```
 private string _LockedOutDate;
        public string LockedOutDate
        {
            get { return _LockedOutDate; }
            set
            {
                _LockedOutDate = DatePicker.CalendarStyleProperty.ToString();
                OnPropertyChanged("LockedOutDate");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use html5 in your code, like bellow:

`<input type="date">`